# delete a selected data of UItableview from core data swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

please help me:

PersonModel.swift

```
class PersonModel: NSObject {

dynamic var name: String?

override init() {

}
init(person: Person) {
    self.name = person.name
}
```

}

in ViewController.swift file i have created an array "var peopleList = PersonModel"  uiang save and fetch function i have saved and fetched all of my data

the following part is for delete a specific selected row data from table and core data at the same time.

//MARK:- UITableViewDataSource

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // let deletePerson = PersonModel()
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let deletePersonData = peopleList[indexPath.row]

       PersonServices.sharedInstance.deletePerson(deletePersonData)
         peopleList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

tableView.reloadData()
}
```

PersonServices.swift

```
class PersonServices: BusinessClass {
static var sharedInstance = PersonServices()

func deletePerson(deletePersonData)-> [PersonModel] {

    var personModels = [PersonModel]();

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: PersonEntity)
    // let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: PersonEntity)
    let predicates = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", "PeopleList[index]")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicates



    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

    do {

        try managedObjectContext.execute(deleteRequest)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    }
```

but i am unable to do that.please help me..

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: yes, solved the problem. see bellow.

Answer (score 2):

i have changed the parameter type of my function. and i have separated the code for core-data from appdelegate file.so no need to use this
 "let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                let OBJECT_Remove = self.ARRAY[Object_TO_Remove]"
statement each time.

change in ViewController.swift for deletePerson function calling parameter:

```
PersonServices.sharedInstance.deletePerson(deletePersonData: deletePersonData)
```

BussinessClass.swift

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class BusinessClass: NSObject {

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "HitList")
    // Declare Options
    let options = [ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : true ]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })


    return container.viewContext
}()



// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = managedObjectContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {

            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

changed the NSPredicate syntax. NSPredicate is like query syntax.

```
func deletePerson(deletePersonData: PersonModel) {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: PersonEntity)

    let predicates = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", deletePersonData.name!)

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicates

   let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

    do {

        try managedObjectContext.execute(deleteRequest)


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**try this code:**`

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                let OBJECT_Remove = self.ARRAY[Object_TO_Remove]
                managedContext.delete(watchList)
                do {
                    try managedContext.save()

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
                self.ARRAY.remove(Object_TO_Remove)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
```

`
hope this works for you